# Как узнать кодировку строки в Perl?

Tags: кодировка, perl

Есть некая строка, ее нужно перевести в некую кодировку, но для этого нужно узнать, в какой кодировке она сейчас.

Есть ли такая возможность? Достаточно просто вывести на экран кодировку строки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывести на экран кодировку строки в Perl](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243638/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-perl)

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае - нет. Это сложная задача - надо перебирать, смотреть, насколько правдоподобные слова получаются...

Мне не удалось что-то быстро найти, разве что
[IMultiLanguage2::DetectCodepageInIStream method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa740985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), но я думаю, какая-нибудь библиотека найдётся.

Ещё посмотрите [How can I programmatically determine the current default codepage of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909913/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-the-current-default-codepage-of-windows), может это Ваш случай?

Upd: а, нет, вон что-то есть именно для Perl'a: [How can I guess the encoding of a string in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970660/how-can-i-guess-the-encoding-of-a-string-in-perl)