# Вывести на экран кодировку строки в Perl

Tags: кодировка, perl

Есть строка $str в неизвестной кодировке. Как вывести на экран эту самую кодировку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, так:

```
use Encode::Detect::Detector;
my $encoding_name = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($str);
print $encoding_name;
```